Reshape seems to be losing observations
i am using reshape in dplyr to turn a long data table into a wide one. but when i do, i seem to be losing some observations.  the data table called "data" is a record of 6 different species of bird observations over 20 years. i would like to make it a wide data table by combining each location/date to include 0s when each species was not observed during a survey.
head(data)
COMMON.NAME LOCALITY.ID OBSERVATION.DATE OBSERVATION.COUNT
1 Bonellis_Eagle    L1210237       12/17/2007                 1
2     Boreal_Owl   L11834228         9/3/2020                 1
3   Saker_Falcon   L12137171        6/27/2021                 1
4   Saker_Falcon    L1218263        4/27/2004                 1
5 Brown_Fish_Owl   L13864707        2/26/2021                 1
6 Bonellis_Eagle   L16000115         8/6/2021                 2

table(data$COMMON.NAME, data$OBSERVATION.COUNT)

                      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  17  20  21  22  26  27  28  31  35  39  40  41  42  50  51  60  62  64  94 100

Bonellis_Eagle        137  51   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Boreal_Owl             18   2   2   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Brown_Fish_Owl         51  29  11   6   4   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Great_Bustard          38  13   7   9   5   2   2   6   2   5   1   3   0   2   2   1   3   1   1   2   3   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
Lanner_Falcon          56  12   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse  17   7   2   6   2   4   3   5   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
Saker_Falcon           61   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
i should have 69 total Saker Falcons (61:1s, 2:2s, and 1:4)
then i reshape the data table using LOCALITY.ID & OBSERVATION.DATE, and use the time.var "COMMON.NAME" to get a wide data table for all 6 species:
d_sens = reshape(data, idvar=c('LOCALITY.ID','OBSERVATION.DATE'),
timevar = 'COMMON.NAME', direction='wide')
finally, i replace the NAs with 0s
colnames(d_sens) = c('location','date','BE','BO','SF','BFO','GB','PS','LF') 
d_sens$BE[is.na(d_sens$BE)] = 0
d_sens$BO[is.na(d_sens$BO)] = 0
d_sens$SF[is.na(d_sens$SF)] = 0
d_sens$BFO[is.na(d_sens$BFO)] = 0
d_sens$GB[is.na(d_sens$GB)] = 0
d_sens$PS[is.na(d_sens$PS)] = 0
d_sens$LF[is.na(d_sens$LF)] = 0

head(d_sens)
location       date BE BO SF BFO GB PS LF
1  L1210237 12/17/2007  1  0  0   0  0  0  0
2 L11834228   9/3/2020  0  1  0   0  0  0  0
3 L12137171  6/27/2021  0  0  1   0  0  0  0
4  L1218263  4/27/2004  0  0  1   0  0  0  0
5 L13864707  2/26/2021  0  0  0   1  0  0  0
6 L16000115   8/6/2021  2  0  0   0  0  0  0
this is the type of data table that i want.
table(d_sens$SF)
0   1   2   4
545  57   2   1
when i compare the number of times of Saker Falcon observations (between the wide "d_sens" and the long "data" files), i've lost 4 of the times 1 was observed. and i don't have any missing values in "data".
any suggestions would be much appreciated.
i tried using the dplyr reshape command:
d_sens = reshape(data, idvar=c('LOCALITY.ID','OBSERVATION.DATE'),
timevar = 'COMMON.NAME', direction='wide')
d_sens looks like the type of table i want, but values are missing.
i also tried the tidyr pivot_wider function (it was suggested in an earlier post), but i can't get that to work.
data %>%
pivot_wider(names_from=c(LOCALITY.ID,OBSERVATION.DATE), values_from=OBSERVATION.COUNT)
but i get this warning:
Warning message:
Values from OBSERVATION.COUNT are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

It could be a problem with duplicates in your original data.
For example, for the same location, the same day and the same specie :
COMMON.NAME     LOCALITY.ID OBSERVATION.DATE    OBSERVATION.COUNT
Bonellis_Eagle  L1218263    03/01/2023          1
Bonellis_Eagle  L1218263    03/01/2023          3


Reshape will keep only the first element when pivoting.
Pivot_wider will throw an error ("Values from XXX are not uniquely
identified"). Also, you didn't use the the appropriate columns when you
called it.

Assuming "data" is the name of your dataframe, before pivoting it may be a good idea to remove duplicates with :
library(dplyr)
data = data %>% distinct(LOCALITY.ID,OBSERVATION.DATE,COMMON.NAME,.keep_all = TRUE)

or if you want to sum observation counts of duplicated rows into one :
data %>%
  group_by(LOCALITY.ID, OBSERVATION.DATE, COMMON.NAME) %>%
  summarise(OBSERVATION.COUNT = sum(OBSERVATION.COUNT),.groups = "drop")

After this step you should have unique rows (1 row = 1 location, 1 day, 1 specie).
Toy dataset :
data=structure(list(COMMON.NAME = c("Bonellis_Eagle", "Lanner_Falcon", 
"Saker_Falcon", "Great_Bustard", "Brown_Fish_Owl", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", 
"Boreal_Owl", "Brown_Fish_Owl", "Lanner_Falcon", "Lanner_Falcon", 
"Brown_Fish_Owl", "Great_Bustard", "Saker_Falcon", "Saker_Falcon", 
"Brown_Fish_Owl", "Boreal_Owl", "Lanner_Falcon", "Bonellis_Eagle", 
"Lanner_Falcon", "Saker_Falcon", "Saker_Falcon", "Brown_Fish_Owl", 
"Bonellis_Eagle", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Great_Bustard", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", 
"Saker_Falcon", "Great_Bustard", "Boreal_Owl", "Brown_Fish_Owl", 
"Lanner_Falcon", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Great_Bustard", 
"Lanner_Falcon", "Boreal_Owl", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Lanner_Falcon", 
"Brown_Fish_Owl", "Boreal_Owl", "Saker_Falcon", "Boreal_Owl", 
"Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Brown_Fish_Owl", "Saker_Falcon", "Bonellis_Eagle", 
"Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Boreal_Owl", "Lanner_Falcon", "Lanner_Falcon", 
"Lanner_Falcon", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", 
"Boreal_Owl", "Lanner_Falcon", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Bonellis_Eagle", 
"Brown_Fish_Owl", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Boreal_Owl", "Lanner_Falcon", 
"Saker_Falcon", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Saker_Falcon", "Great_Bustard", 
"Saker_Falcon", "Boreal_Owl", "Saker_Falcon", "Great_Bustard", 
"Saker_Falcon", "Brown_Fish_Owl", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Boreal_Owl", 
"Lanner_Falcon", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Boreal_Owl", 
"Great_Bustard", "Saker_Falcon", "Bonellis_Eagle", "Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse", 
"Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse"), LOCALITY.ID = c("L1218263", "L11834228", 
"L12137171", "L1210237", "L16000115", "L13864707", "L1210237", 
"L11834228", "L16000115", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L16000115", 
"L16000115", "L13864707", "L16000115", "L12137171", "L13864707", 
"L16000115", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L13864707", 
"L13864707", "L11834228", "L12137171", "L1218263", "L11834228", 
"L13864707", "L13864707", "L1210237", "L13864707", "L1210237", 
"L12137171", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L16000115", 
"L1210237", "L11834228", "L1218263", "L1218263", "L1210237", 
"L13864707", "L12137171", "L13864707", "L11834228", "L1218263", 
"L1210237", "L16000115", "L1218263", "L13864707", "L1210237", 
"L1218263", "L13864707", "L16000115", "L1210237", "L11834228", 
"L12137171", "L16000115", "L16000115", "L13864707", "L12137171", 
"L12137171", "L13864707", "L13864707", "L16000115", "L11834228", 
"L1210237", "L1210237", "L1210237", "L11834228", "L12137171", 
"L12137171", "L16000115", "L13864707", "L12137171", "L11834228", 
"L1218263", "L11834228", "L12137171", "L11834228", "L11834228"
), OBSERVATION.DATE = c("03/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "05/01/2023", 
"06/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "06/01/2023", 
"03/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "02/01/2023", 
"02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "05/01/2023", 
"06/01/2023", "03/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "02/01/2023", 
"03/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "01/01/2023", 
"02/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "05/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "03/01/2023", 
"03/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "03/01/2023", 
"04/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "03/01/2023", 
"06/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "05/01/2023", 
"06/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "03/01/2023", 
"03/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "07/01/2023", 
"01/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "07/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "05/01/2023", 
"04/01/2023", "05/01/2023", "01/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "05/01/2023", 
"05/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "06/01/2023", 
"04/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "05/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "01/01/2023", 
"05/01/2023", "04/01/2023", "06/01/2023", "01/01/2023"), OBSERVATION.COUNT = c(1, 
5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
2, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 4, 4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 2, 
4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -82L))

Pivoting (+ setting names of columns, removing NAs, sorting the df).
library(tidyr)
output = data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'COMMON.NAME',values_from = 'OBSERVATION.COUNT') %>%
  rename('location'='LOCALITY.ID',
         'date'='OBSERVATION.DATE',
         'BE'='Bonellis_Eagle',
         'LF'='Lanner_Falcon',
         'SF'='Saker_Falcon',
         'GB'='Great_Bustard',
         'BFO'='Brown_Fish_Owl',
         'PS'='Pin_tailed_Sandgrouse',
         'BO'='Boreal_Owl') %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),~replace_na(.x,0))) %>% 
  arrange(location,date) %>% 
  select(location,date,BE,BFO,BO,GB,LF,PS,SF)

Output :
# A tibble: 38 × 9
   location  date          BE   BFO    BO    GB    LF    PS    SF
   <chr>     <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 L11834228 01/01/2023     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
 2 L11834228 02/01/2023     0     0     1     0     0     0     5
 3 L11834228 03/01/2023     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4 L11834228 04/01/2023     0     5     4     0     0     0     0
 5 L11834228 05/01/2023     0     0     0     0     0     0     4
 6 L11834228 06/01/2023     0     1     0     0     5     1     0
 7 L1210237  01/01/2023     0     0     1     0     0     5     0
 8 L1210237  02/01/2023     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9 L1210237  03/01/2023     0     0     0     4     4     0     1
10 L1210237  04/01/2023     0     0     0     0     5     0     0
# ℹ 28 more rows


hi E.Wiest, i think you're right about the problem with duplicates. when i run your code (for either reshape or pivot_wider) i get a different, but still strange result.
0    1    2   4
545  53   6   1
now there are only 53 1s, and 6 2s.
there should be 61 1s and 2 2s.
thank you for the help.

You're right. There was a mistake with the renaming of the columns. Post has been edited. Don't forget to remove duplicates (code has been updated) before pivoting.

That's it. thank you.
now i need to think about whether i should be including the duplicate values or not (a more philosophical question). but you found the missing birds for which i was searching after pivoting. thanks again.
